# How to add a "Authorization=Bearer" header with Indy in Delphi?

Tags: http, delphi, access-token, indy, bearer-token

I'm trying to do a POST request using an access_token, and it works fine using POSTMAN, but when I try to do the same request on Delphi, I can't find a way to add the "Authorization=Bearer eyxxxxxx..." to the Request header, as POSTMAN does.

**POSTMAN Request (working well):**

POST /somepath HTTP/1.1
Host: someurl.com.br
Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiJ9.....
Content-Type: application/json

(body content ommited)

**Indy Request generated by Delphi, captured by HTTP Analyzer (always returning 401 Forbidden error, because the absence of "Authorization=Bearer" part):**

POST /somepath HTTP/1.1
Host: someurl.com.br
Content-Type: application/json

(body content ommited)

I've tried to add the header using the code below, but the header part with the "Authorization=Bearer eyxxxxxx..." isn't generated on Request, returning the 401 Forbidden error.

```
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization=Bearer ' + txtToken.Text);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just found the problem. I added the wrong separator between the "Authorization" and "Bearer" words.

**Wrong:**

```
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization=Bearer ' + txtToken.Text);
```

**Correct:**

```
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization:Bearer ' + txtToken.Text);
```

After replacing the '=' by ':', I received the expected response, like the one received by POSTMAN.

Comment: You should use the `CustomHeaders.Values[]` property instead, then you don't have to worry about the separator at all: `FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Valus['Authorization'] := 'Bearer ' + txtToken.Text;`

Comment: It worked that way too. Thanks for the alternative Remy, and thanks for all your support on Stackoverflow. I've learned a lot on other questions already answered by you. =)

Comment: @RemyLebeau i still got http/1.0 500 Internal Server Error