# Where to attach access token to google REST request in Delphi?

Tags: rest, delphi, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-oauth

I am trying to insert an event into my Google Calendar via the Delphi REST controls, but I am uncertain where to add the access token to my request.
 My Code looks like this:

```
var
  evt : String;    
begin
  ResetRESTComponentsToDefaults;
  RESTClient.BaseURL := 'https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3';       
  RESTClient.Authenticator := OAuth2_GoogleCalendar;
  RESTRequest.Resource := 'calendars/primary/events'; 
  evt:='{"summary":"test","description":"test","id":"06824945162f4204bfdc041ae1bbae85","start":{"date":"2018-04-10"},"end":{"date":"2018-04-10"},"guestsCanInviteOthers":false,"visibility":"private"}'

  RESTRequest.AddParameter('access_token',OAuth2_GoogleTasks.AccessToken,pkHTTPHEADER);
  RESTRequest.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTRequest.Body.Add(evt,ctAPPLICATION_JSON);

  RESTRequest.Execute;
end;
```

The scope is `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar`
If I send it in like this I this error:

```
{
  "error":
  {
    "errors":
    [
        {
        "domain":"global",
        "reason":"required",
        "message":"Login Required",
        "locationType":"header",
        "location":"Authorization"
      }
    ]
,
    "code":401,
    "message":"Login Required"
  }
}
```

Appending `?access_token={accessToken}` to the end of the url i get 
error 400, parseError.

Where should I add the access token to the request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cant help much with Delphi its been years since i have used it, but you have a two options with regard to adding your access token.

First is to just add it as a parameter on the base url

```
?access_token=TokenHere
```

The second option is to send it as an authorization header on your request its a bearer token.

```
Authorization : Bearer cn389ncoiwuencr
```

After a bit of googling i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38274129/1841839)

```
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.FoldLines := False;
FIdHTTP.Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization:Bearer ' + txtToken.Text);
```