# How do integrate aplication Delphi with Google Calendar API, How do insert calendar?

Tags: delphi, https, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to send a request with a post method with content in the body which is the calendar information that will be included in the API
But on request it returns 401 unauthorized and I don't know where to place the Acces Token in Delphi's REST components or where to place the Scopo that I believe is important for Request to work.
Thank you very much in advance for devs help

My Code

```
procedure TOAuth2TesterFrm.incluir_btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
json,token: String;
begin
token:=RefreshTokenEdt.Text;
json:=(
'{"kind": "calendar#calendarListEntry", "etag": "0", "id": "iago21092020@gmail.com", ' +
'"summary": "Calendario Outro", "description": "Descrição do evento", '   +
'{"date": "2020 August 11", "dateTime": "2020-08-11T17:35:36+03:00"}'+
'"timeZone": "Brasília-DF", "colorId": "15", "backgroundColor": "#9fc6e7", "foregroundColor": "#000000", ' +
'"selected": true, "accessRole": "owner", "primary": true, '+
 '"defaultReminders": [{"method": "popup", "minutes": 30}, {"method": "email", "minutes": 10}], '  +
'"notificationSettings": {"notifications": [{"method": "email", "type": "eventCreation"}, ' +
'{"method": "email", "type": "eventChange"}, {"method": "email", "type": "eventCancellation"}, ' +
'{"method": "email", "type": "eventResponse"}]}}');
try
    client.ResetToDefaults;
    request.ResetToDefaults;
    response.ResetToDefaults;
    client.BaseURL:='https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3';
    response.ContentType := 'application/json';
    request.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
    request.Body.ClearBody;
    client.AcceptEncoding:='UTF-8';
    client.ContentType:='text/html';
    request.Resource := 'calendars';
    request.Params.AddHeader('Authorization','Bearer '+token);
    request.Params.ParameterByName('Authorization').Options := [poDoNotEncode];
    request.AddBody(json);
    request.Execute;
    ShowMessage(request.Response.StatusCode.ToString);
finally
      request.Free;
      response.Free;
      client.Free;

end;
  end;
```

Comment: The authorization header is "Authorization: <type> <credentials>".  Notice the spaces and that the value includes <type> and <credentials>. Skipping spaces or skipping the type completely will not work.

Comment: How to add the header ?? because I do not know

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add a "Authorization=Bearer" header with Indy in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272627/how-to-add-a-authorization-bearer-header-with-indy-in-delphi)

Comment: Soso because I using REST components and this example is using HTTP component

Comment: Have you tried using `request.Params.AddHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);`?

Comment: Yes lamblichus, I'm using exacty this.

Comment: Helpe me somebody