# How to use the AddAuthparameter procedure?

Tags: api, delphi, request

I have to add an authorization to a REST request in Delphi.

Can someone give me an example how should it call the AddAuthParameter procedure?

I am doing this code in an onclick event of a button :

```
authjo, auth1, auth2, auth3, auth4, auth5, auth6, auth7, auth8, auth9, auth10 : string;

authjo := auth1 + auth2 + auth3 + auth4 + auth5 + auth6 + auth7 + auth8 + auth9 + auth10 ;

Restrequest4.AddAuthParameter('Authorization',authjo,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);

Restrequest4.Execute;
```

But this does not use thes the Authorization token 'authjo' and i don't know why.
I must have Authorization like this "Authorization Bearer :token" am i not constructing well in the code ?

Comment: What's the error message?

Comment: What happens? Did you see the docs http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/REST.Client.TCustomRESTRequest.AddAuthParameter ?

Comment: It says there is no overloaded version of what i am calling

Comment: I have to call this way or how ? : Restrequest4.AddAuthParameter('Authorization',authjo,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);

Comment: What do you mean with "does not work"? Does the compiler complain? Is the web site not accepting the token?

Comment: The compiler complains

Comment: "does not work" -> what does not work?, "compiler complains" -> what's the error message? You probably need to include the REST.Types unit

Comment: The error message is  : "There is no overloaded version of AddAuthParameter "

Comment: Please show more of your code including the declaration of the used variables and the uses clause.

Comment: Now i dont have compile error anymore, i added REST.Types and this way works :  Restrequest4.AddAuthParameter('Authorization',authjo,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);

But this does not use thes the Authorization token 'authjo' and i don't know why.

Comment: I must have Authorization like this "Authorization Bearer :token" am i not constructing well in the code ?

Answer (score 1):

If the authentication expects a Bearer token, you must add that to your call:

```
Restrequest4.AddAuthParameter('Authorization','Bearer ' + authjo,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
```

Comment: I am doing it that way but it responds that 'Authentication Header not found' and i don't understand why

Comment: Seems you need to show more of your code. Perhaps the Delphi version could be of interest, too.

Comment: Restrequest4.AddAuthParameter('Authorization',authjo,TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);

Restrequest4.Execute;

Answer (score 1):

Having messed around with Delphi to access an API (In my case Trakt), I managed to authenticate with OAuth2. But I ran into the very same problem as you did.

I have just asked my question here:
[Accessing TRAKT API from Delphi - issues with Bearer authentication [SOLVED]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65191591/accessing-trakt-api-from-delphi-issues-with-bearer-authentication)

As I understand it, the root cause it that adding headers like we do, will create a parameter entry that is "Authorize=Bearer [token]" whereas it should be "Authorize:Bearer [token]".

See here:

[How to add a "Authorization=Bearer" header with Indy in Delphi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38272627/how-to-add-a-authorization-bearer-header-with-indy-in-delphi)

I have managed to mitigate the issue and would like to reference to that thread.

Also, the tool Fiddler was most helpful to see what my app actually sent and what it got back.

Comment: Thank you for the advice