# Accessing TRAKT API from Delphi - issues with Bearer authentication

Tags: api, rest, delphi, authorization, token

Using TOauth2Authenticator, TRESTClient, TRESTRequest, TRESTResponseDataSet, TRESTResponse, TFDmemtable and a TDataSource have I managed to connect to the Trakt API, and authenticate my application and get a code in return and lastly use that code to get a token.

So now I should be able to list the movies with the below code.

```
RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://trakt.tv/';
RESTRequest1.Resource := 'calendars/my/movies/{start_date}/{days}';
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('Authorization','Bearer ' + TraktAccessToken.Text,pkHTTPHEADER);
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('trakt-api-version', '2', pkHTTPHEADER);
RESTRequest1.AddParameter('trakt-api-key', TraktClientId.Text, pkHTTPHEADER);
    
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('start_date', '2019-05-05', pkURLSEGMENT); // Dummy date
RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('days', '7', pkURLSEGMENT);                // Dummy time

RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmGET;
RESTRequest1.Execute;
```

But this wouldn't work. The command sets the Authorization to "Authorization=Bearer [TOKEN]" whereas my understanding after trying to read up is that it must me "Authorization:Bearer [TOKEN]". (Mind the "=" vs ":")

I have tried removing the Authorization line and replacing with poking the data not in the headers but the component properties, like so:

```
Trakt_OAuth.TokenType := TOAuth2TokenType.ttBEARER;
Trakt_OAuth.AccessToken := TraktAccessToken.Text;
```

Also this:

```
RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('Authorization','Bearer ' + TraktAccessToken.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER);
```

Both options fail in the very same manner. The only thing I have located is this option, when you poke a string into your customer headers:

```
Request.CustomHeaders.Add('Authorization: Bearer ' + sToken)
```

By the CustomHeaders method isn't available in the RESTRequest class.

Thinking I was ready to go really dirty to fix it, I realised I could read out the parameter item:

```
Whatever := RESTRequest1.Params.Items[5].ToString
```

Now I can change the string - replace the "=" with a ":", but that doesn't help as I can't write it back.

It's not that I have run into a corner case - OAuth2 giving a token that is then used in conjunction with bearer authentication is how this works. I just seems to fail to do it ...

Comment: *The command sets the Authorization to "Authorization=Bearer [TOKEN]"* How do you lnow that?

Comment: Oliver: I have a bit of debug code that extract the parameters set:

Memo2.Lines.Text := Memo2.Lines.Text + sLineBreak + 'Parameter 0: ' +
    RESTRequest1.Params.Items[0].ToString;

I extract the full list of parameters this way (clumsy with no loop but it's a fixed set of parameters and it will be gone in the final version anyways so not optimized).

Comment: That's what I thought: it's just debugging information. It doesn't prove that the header is actually sent that way.

Comment: Using the tool Fiddler Everywhere (https://docs.telerik.com/fiddler-everywhere/introduction) I was able to have a full look at the real communication sent during the session, including depacking the HTTPS ones (you need to enable this specifically in the settings)

Answer (score 2):

In my case, the space after "Bearer" was replaced with %20 of
`RESTRequest.Params.AddItem('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + ...)`, Microfot Graph couldn't parse it correctly. The suggested solution from Pontus did the trick.

```
OAuth2Authenticator.TokenType := TOAuth2TokenType.ttBEARER;
OAuth2Authenticator.AccessToken :=  'Your_Access_token';
```

Answer (score 1):

This has worked for me:

```
  LParam := RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem;
  LParam.Name := 'Authorization';
  LParam.Kind := TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER;
  LParam.Value := 'Bearer ' + sToken;
```

I seem to recall for one service, there needed to be *no space character* between Bearer and the token. Weird.

Comment: My debug code returns this (where the actual keys are removed): 

`https://trakt.tv/calendars/my/movies/2019-05-05/7
Token:       (TOKEN REMOVED)
Parameter 0: [URL-SEGMENT / E] start_date=2019-05-05
Parameter 1: [URL-SEGMENT / E] days=7
Parameter 2: [HEADER / E] Content-type=application/json
Parameter 3: [HEADER / E] Authorization=Bearer (TOKEN REMOVED)
Parameter 4: [HEADER / E] trakt-api-version=2
Parameter 5: [HEADER / E] trakt-api-key=(API KEY REMOVED)`

Comment: Without knowing what your debug code actually does, that output doesn't mean anything. If you're suggesting it uses "=" instead of ":" for headers, then something else is going on

Comment: I installed Fiddler Everywhere (link as per the previous answer) to confirm that this was actually happening..

Comment: To address the space character issue, you could try turning on the poDoNotEncode in the parameter Options.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try this because you don't have to encode your Bearer parameter:

```
RESTRequest1.AddAuthParameter('Authorization','Bearer ' + TraktAccessToken.Text, TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
```

Comment: Thanks! The `[poDoNotEncode]` did the trick for me. Don´t know why this answer isn´t upvoted more.